# Tizen - Getting App to Request Permission

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

so I'm trying to get my Tizen app to check and ask for permission on initialization, but the following code does not work as expected

```
        var readPrivilege = "http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.read";

        function readRPSuccess(x){
            alert("Success" + JSON.stringify(x));
        }

        function readRPError(e){
            alert("error "+ JSON.stringify(e));
        }

        function readCHSuccess(){
        }

        function readCHError(){
            tizen.ppm.requestPermission(readPrivilege, readRPSuccess, readRPError);
        }

        tizen.ppm.checkPermission(readPrivilege, readCHSuccess, readCHError);
```

This sniped of code is in my init fuction of my main.js file. I get the same result from my watch that runs 4.0.0.1 and my emulator that runs 3.0. Required Tizen version on my xml file is 2.3

**Result:** black screen with no content.

**Expected:** page asking for read permission.

**UPDATE:** So I installed a template project "HeartRateMonitor", changed the Tizen version required version to 4 on the xml file, and added the code below. Note the code was installed on the init function of the main.js. This time I changed it to request for the `healthinfo` permission and it worked as expected. When I changed it to either of the `filesystem` permissions it doesn't work.

```
    function onSuccess() {
        alert("yay");
    }

    function onError() {
        alert("nay");
    }
    tizen.ppm.requestPermission("http://tizen.org/privilege/healthinfo",onSuccess, onError);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the following page: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/web-application/understanding-tizen-programming/security-and-api-privileges
`filesystem.read` is not a privacy privilege hence no need to use `ppm` for it. See privacy column of the table.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code does nothing because of invalid usage of [checkPermission API](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/5.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/ppm.html#PrivacyPrivilegeManager::checkPermission):

> tizen.ppm.checkPermission(readPrivilege, readCHSuccess, readCHError);

This method is synchronous and it should be used as follows:

```
if (tizen.ppm.checkPermission(readPrivilege) != "PPM_ALLOW") {
  tizen.ppm.requestPermission(readPrivilege, readRPSuccess, readRPError);
} else {
  console.log("already allowed!");
}
```

When using above code for readPrivilege, it alwask print the message about no need to ask.

You probably would like to request accessing filesystem. To do this, you need to request [proper privilege](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/training/web-application/understanding-tizen-programming/security-and-api-privileges#nonAPI), not directly related to filesystem API. For below destinations:

- internal memory - http://tizen.org/privilege/mediastorage
- external memory - http://tizen.org/privilege/externalstorage

With proper privilege, popup asking for permission will be opened.
Also notice that tizen.ppm api is available since 4.0, so add proper required version in your app's config.xml file.

Comment: Thank for you feedback. The provided code works if the `readPrivilege` is a single string, but if I try checking for multiple permissions in a loop I get a `PMM_DENY_FOREVER` message.

Comment: I used below code successfully:
var privs = ["http://tizen.org/privilege/mediastorage", "http://tizen.org/privilege/externalstorage"]
for (i in privs) {
  console.log(privs[i]);
  tizen.ppm.requestPermission(privs[i], (s, p) => {console.log(p + ": " + s)}, (e) => {console.log(e)} )
}

Answer (score 0):

How about below technique?

```
var cameraPrivilege = "http://tizen.org/privilege/camera";
var result = tizen.ppm.checkPermission(cameraPrivilege);
switch (result) {
    case "PPM_ALLOW":
        /* Update UI and start accessing protected functionality */
        break;
   case "PPM_DENY":
        /* Show a message and terminate the application */
        break;
   case "PPM_ASK":
        /* Request permission */
        break;
}

/* Define PermissionSuccessCallback */
function permissionSuccess(result, privilege)
{
    console.log("User's action for privilege " + privilege + " was to: " + result);
}

/* Define ErrorCallback */
function errorCallback(response)
{
    console.log("The following error occurred: " + response.name);
}

var cameraPrivilege = "http://tizen.org/privilege/camera";
tizen.ppm.requestPermission(cameraPrivilege, permissionSuccess, errorCallback);
```

For more details, please check official doc [here](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/security/privacy-related-permissions?langredirect=1).